# On NFS, are multiple opens of a file guaranteed to get the same inode?

Tags: nfs, inode

I'm having a hard time finding information on this. Most people seem to care if inodes are unique, which is not my concern. What I need to know is whether opening a file multiple times from a process will always get the same inode back from the NFS server.

Comment: Some clue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11097731/10765659).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! I think I can safely assume that there will not be NFS server restarts in my situation, though. Maybe? Are those things that happen transparently?